# Docusign Stamp/Print file name to uploaded document

Tags: docusignapi

Is there anyway I can stamp or print file name for the documents uploaded to an envelope through REST API?
Went trough EnvelopeDocuments parameters but no luck.

What I'd like to do is, when uploading the documents to existing envelope, I'd like Docusign to print or stamp the file name onto the document something like what Docusign did for the Envelope Id on the document. Eg. print "Agreement.pdf" somewhere on the document so signee can tell the separation of the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seems DS has this functionality.

Anyway, I found the workaround to use [EnvelopeDocuments](https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/esign/restapi?categories=Envelopes&tags=EnvelopeDocuments&operations=list) to get the detail documents then loop the documents and put a read only [textTabs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The [listEnvelopeDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/) api should provide the name of the document that is supplied during the creation of the envelope.

Here is a sample response

```
{
  "envelopeId": "13116d4e-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-48cd64fece76",
  "envelopeDocuments": [
    {
        "documentId": "1",
        "name": "Agreement.pdf",
        "type": "content",
        "order": "1",
        "pages": "1"
    },
    {
        "documentId": "certificate",
        "name": "Summary",
        "type": "summary",    
        "order": "999",
        "pages": "2"

    }
  ]
}
```

You can also use [EnvelopeDocumentFields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocumentFields/) api to store and retrieve additional metadata related to the documents in the envelope.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But you might misunderstood my question. What I'd like to do is, when uploading the documents to existing envelope, I'd like Docusign to print or stamp the file name onto the document something like what Docusign did for the Envelope Id on the document. Eg. print "Agreement.pdf" somewhere on the document so signee can tell the separation of the documents.